# Angular: binding click event to element after compilation

Tags: angular, typescript

I´m working in a application for students using angular 5, where the user is gonna be able to see some documents, when the user get inside of the document a sets of tools are gonna be displayed, one of those tools is a marker tool, that allow the user mark text on the document, the markers are persistent so are saved on the server and set and id for each marker on the document. The document is structured this way:

```
[{
        "chapterId": "254125",
        "title": "Some randome title",
        "blocks": [{
                "blockId": "12654654",
                "blockContent": {
                    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit harum ex fuga magni ea, fugiat rem voluptas odio alias, voluptates doloribus adipisci velit! Ullam, eveniet perferendis. Fugiat quis suscipit ipsa."
                }
            },
            {
                "blockId": "12654654",
                "blockContent": {
                    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit harum ex fuga magni ea, fugiat rem voluptas odio alias, voluptates doloribus adipisci velit! Ullam, eveniet perferendis. Fugiat quis suscipit ipsa."
                }
            },
            {
                "blockId": "12654654",
                "blockContent": {
                    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit harum ex fuga magni ea, fugiat rem voluptas odio alias, voluptates doloribus adipisci velit! Ullam, eveniet perferendis. Fugiat quis suscipit ipsa."
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "chapterId": "254125",
        "title": "Another randome title",
        "blocks": [{
                "blockId": "12654654",
                "blockContent": {
                    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit harum ex fuga magni ea, fugiat rem voluptas odio alias, voluptates doloribus adipisci velit! Ullam, eveniet perferendis. Fugiat quis suscipit ipsa."
                }
            },
            {
                "blockId": "12654654",
                "blockContent": {
                    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit harum ex fuga magni ea, fugiat rem voluptas odio alias, voluptates doloribus adipisci velit! Ullam, eveniet perferendis. Fugiat quis suscipit ipsa."
                }
            },
            {
                "blockId": "12654654",
                "blockContent": {
                    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit harum ex fuga magni ea, fugiat rem voluptas odio alias, voluptates doloribus adipisci velit! Ullam, eveniet perferendis. Fugiat quis suscipit ipsa."
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Where each block is a paragraph in the chapter, looping the chapter and the blocks of each chapter i build the document it self ([Document example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj08b.png)), now when i bring the markers back from the server i get this object:

```
{
  "id": 20,
  "start": 125,
  "end": 258,
  "color": "red",
  "chapterId": 12631561,
  "blockId": 121651
}
```

with this i search for the right chapter and the right block to place the marker in the right position in to the text block:

```
  public placeMarkerOnBlock(chapter, marker): any {
    let tempText: string = '';

    /* Here  we loop the blocks to find the righ
    *  one to place marker.
    */
    chapter.blocks.some((block) => {
      if (marker.blockId === block.blockId) {
        /*
        * Ones the block is founded i place the marker
        */
        const blockText = block.blockElement.text;
        this.counter(blockText, marker, counters);
        counters.endTags += counters.startTags;
        const start = marker.start + counters.startTags;
        const end = marker.end + counters.endTags;

        const textSelected = blockText.substring(start, end);
        tempText += block.blockElement.text.substring(0, start);
        tempText += `<mark class="${marker.color}" alt="${marker.id}">`;
        tempText += textSelected;
        tempText += '</mark>';
        tempText += block.blockElement.text.substring(end);

        block.blockElement.text = tempText;
        tempText = '';

        return false;
      }
    });
    return chapter;
  }
```

basically what i do here is get the text from the block and cut it in 3 parts, the text before the marker, the text after the marker and the text from the marker, then the text selected i wrapped in a `mark` tag and paste the 3 part again for then replace the text with the marker for the original.

now after all this explanation, what i need to do is attach(bind) to the marker a `(click)=""` event, for when the user click in one of the markers in the text, display a small bubble with a button to remove that marker that was clicked [Example of marker and bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYoE8.png), but i haven´t been able to do it, because the `(click)=""` event basically is added to the marker after compilation process of the application, is there any other way to achieve this....?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the issue  that you are facing is because you are trying to attach an event on a HTML which is generating at run-time and which is dynamic in nature.
So, if you are using jquery than you can attach a click event on dynamic HTML in the following manner:-

```
 $(document).on("click", "a.remove" , function() {
        // write your logic here
    });
```

where "a.remove" :-
a : an anchor tag generating dynamically,
remove : a normal class on anchor.

In case you don't want to use jquery and you want to do everything in angular then you can load your HTML in life cycle hook i.e ngOnInit() and when the HTML is fully loaded than you can use ngAfterViewInit() to create click event on dynamically generated HTML.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {

 // write logic to add click event on generated html
}

 ngOnInit() {
    //load your data here
}
```

Comment: The click event is not gonna be attach to the  bubble but to the text marked  `<mark>Selected text</mark>` and the other issue with this solution is that the user is gonna be creating new markers in the document while is using the document so in this case i would not be able to bind the event to the new marker.